# If else statment not working in php

Tags: php

working on a login for some course work and some reason it will never recent the else if even if the criteria is satisfied, I've prove this using prints of the variables any help will be much appreciated.

```
if($_SESSION['username'] == $row['UserID'] and $password == $row['password'] and $row['loginAttempts'] < 3)  
        {
            //setting student session and redirecting
            if ($row["type"] == "0")
            {
                echo "student login";
                $_SESSION['student'] = 'true';
                $resetLoginAttempts;
                //header('Location: studenthome.php');
            }   
            //setting staff session and redirecting
            if ($row["type"] == "1") 
            {
                echo "Staff login";
                $_SESSION['staff'] = 'true';
                $resetLoginAttempts;
                //header('Location: staffhome.php');S
            }
        }
        //correct username but wrong password not over max login attempts
        elseif($_SESSION['username'] == $row['UserID'] and $password =! $row['password'] and $row['loginAttempts'] < 3)
        {
            echo "wrong pass";
            $incrementLoginAttemts;
        }
        //correct username, incorrect or correct password but user has used their 3 login attempts
        elseif($_SESSION['username'] == $row['UserID'] and $row['loginAttempts'] == 3)
        {
            echo "You've have been locked out, please contact the system admin";
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['username'] =! $row['UserID'] and $row['loginAttempts'] =! 3)
        {
            echo "wrong user name";
        }
    }
```

Comment: There're three `elseif`s here. Which one not work?

Comment: are these supposed to be function calls? `$resetLoginAttempts;` and `$incrementLoginAttemts;`

Answer (score 1):

You inverted the "not equals" and are getting a syntax error, but aren't checking for errors.

All

```
=!
```

should be

```
!=
```

Demo of the error in various PHP versions: https://3v4l.org/8Xo7e

Correct execution: https://3v4l.org/Xt2W5

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bracket in if condition like this:

`if(($_SESSION['username'] == $row['UserID']) and ($password == $row['password']) and ($row['loginAttempts'] < 3))`
Hopefully this is will be your lucky